# Symfony 3: Global call for the Controller after user login

Tags: symfony, controller

Because I have many controllers, after the user is logged in, I want to transfer some user settings to Twig. But I don't want to make it in each controller:

Eg:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $settings = $user->getSettings();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility to make it at a higher level from the call of the DefaultController?

Comment: use `app.user` in your twig file, to get current logged user   https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#the-app-global-variable

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

Use app.user variable in Twig which is globally accessible:

```
{{ app.user.username }}
```

More info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#the-app-global-variable

**Solution 2**

Write custom Twig function:

```php
// src/Twig/UserExtension.php
namespace App\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class UserExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    Security $security

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        // Avoid calling getUser() in the constructor: auth may not
        // be complete yet. Instead, store the entire Security object.
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('get_user_settings', [$this, 'getUserSettings']),
        ];
    }

    public function getUserSettings()
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
        return $user->getSettings();
    }
}
```

Usage in Twig:

```
{{ get_user_settings().setting1 }}
```

More info: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

How to inject current logged user: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-fetching-the-user-from-a-service

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful also.

Comment: This is the best practice. This is an existing service in Symfony. You will be able to retrieve all user information from here without adding anything in your controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe I don't describe it clearly. This is the solution I have searched for:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Subscriber;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class ControllerSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var TokenStorageInterface
     */
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * ControllerSubscriber constructor.
     *
     * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @param FilterControllerEvent $event
     */
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user = $token->getUser()) {
            return;
        }

        // if no user
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return;
        } else {
            // .... do something
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => array(array('onKernelController', 1)),
        );
    }
}
```

**services.yml**

```
app.controller.subscriber:
    class: AppBundle\Subscriber\ControllerSubscriber
    arguments: ["@security.token_storage","@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"]
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```